# How to fetch lastChild, firstChild and nextSibling content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, nextsibling

I would like to know how can I fetch the lastChild, firstChild and nextSibling content in JavaScript.
This is my sample code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="first">content 1</div>
    <div id="second">content 2</div>
    <div id="third">content 3</div>
</div>
<script>
alert (document.getElementById('main').firstChild.nodeValue);
alert (document.getElementById('main').lastChild.nodeValue);
alert (document.getElementById('first').nextSibling.nodeValue);
</script>
```

I tried this code, but they did not work ... an empty alert opens only!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted `firstElementChild`, `nextElementSibling` and `lastElementChild` ?
Then

```
alert (document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.innerHTML);
alert (document.getElementById('main').lastElementChild.innerHTML);
alert (document.getElementById('first').nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
```

Explain clearly, please, what do you mean by using "exactly"?
You can edit it:

```
document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.innerHTML="some text";
```

You can store it:

```
var fec=document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.innerHTML;
```

You can remove it:

```
document.getElementById('main').removeChild(document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild);
```

You can replace text in it:

```
document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.innerHTML=document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.innerHTML.replace(/new_text/g,"text_to_replace")
```

You can split it into an array of characters:

```
var array=document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.innerHTML.split("");
```

You can add some text to it:

```
document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild.appendChild("some text");
```

Comment: Unfortunately No. It returns `undefined`.

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi How? `document.getElementById('main').firstElementChild` - use it exactly